# JQuery pagination not working with AJAX script

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, frontend

Im using the Jquery for pagination of my data tables and it is working great. However, when i add some AJAX script to load data without page refresh, the pagination function is not working anymore. Can anyone point out my mistake? my code is as below:

My table:

```
<table id="data-table" class="table table-striped border " style="width:100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>License Plate</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Date</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            @foreach($bg_records as $bg_record)

                @if($bg_record -> status == 1)
                    <tr id="">
                        <th scope="row">{{ $loop->iteration }}</th>
                        <td>{{ $bg_record -> lp}}</td>
                        <td> PASS</td>
                        <td>{{  Carbon\Carbon::parse($bg_record->timestamp)->format('h:i:s')}}</td>
                        <td>{{  Carbon\Carbon::parse($bg_record->timestamp)->format('d-m-Y')}}</td>
                    </tr>

                @else
                    <tr id="">
                        <th scope="row">{{ $loop->iteration }}</th>
                        <td>{{ $bg_record -> lp}}</td>
                        <td> FAILED</td>

                        <td>{{  Carbon\Carbon::parse($bg_record->timestamp)->format('h:i:s')}}</td>
                        <td>{{  Carbon\Carbon::parse($bg_record->timestamp)->format('d-m-Y')}}</td>
                    </tr>

                @endif


            @endforeach

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

My AJAX script to load the table without page refresh

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var delay = 1000;

    var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
        $('#data-table').load(' #data-table');
    }, delay);

</script>
```

JQuery pagination script

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#data-table').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
```